# Can Pytorch dataset transforms be based on the index of the data in the dataset?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

I'm trying to transform the data in a Pytorch dataset by creating a custom class, 'ReplaceDataTransform()', that is called by TUDataset() and will perform the transform.

The problem I have is that transform is applied to each data entry one at a time. I want my transform to be applied to each data entry based on the data entry's index. Specifically the transform I want on each data entry is that the properties of the entry be replaced by properties I have stored in some Pytorch tensors run in code blocks earlier.

Is there a way to perform transforms that relies on the index of the data entry?

Answer (score 0):

- you can perform transforms on a PyTorch dataset based on the index of each data entry.
- To achieve this, you can create a custom class, `ReplaceDataTransform()`, that inherits from the `PyTorch` `torchvision.transforms.Transform` class.
  -Within this class, you can define the logic for replacing the properties of each data entry based on the index.

  ```
  import torch
  from torchvision import transforms
  class ReplaceDataTransform(transforms.Transform):
      def __init__(self, replacement_tensors):
          super(ReplaceDataTransform, self).__init__()
          self.replacement_tensors = replacement_tensors
      def __call__(self, sample):
          # Assuming 'index' is a key in your data dictionary          
          index = sample['index']  
          replacement_data = self.replacement_tensors[index]
          # Replace the properties of the data entry with the replacement data
          sample['property1'] = replacement_data['property1']
          sample['property2'] = replacement_data['property2']
          # Add more properties as needed

          return sample
  ```
- In this example, the `ReplaceDataTransform` class takes a `replacement_tensors` argument, which should be a PyTorch tensor containing the replacement data for each index.
- `__call__()` method is called for each data entry, and it replaces the properties of the data entry with the corresponding replacement data based on the index.

To use this custom transform with the `TUDataset()` class, you can pass an instance of the `ReplaceDataTransform` class as the transform argument when creating the dataset:

```
from torch_geometric.datasets import TUDataset
# Assuming you have already created the replacement_tensors
replace_transform = ReplaceDataTransform(replacement_tensors)

dataset = TUDataset(root='path/to/dataset', name='your_dataset_name', 
                    transform=replace_transform)
```

Now, when you access the data entries from the dataset, the properties of each entry will be replaced based on the index using the logic defined in the `ReplaceDataTransform` class.

Comment: Hi @Raymond Reddington, thanks for replying. I am looking at line 9, and I'm not sure I have a key 'index' in each sample. Also, I'm assuming the value returned by sample['index'] is the index of the sample, but I'm not sure each sample will include its index in the dictionary. This is something I had hoped would be the case in the sample somewhere, but from looking at the code it is not. Would you change the code to solve this issue? Thanks again for the advice.